# Django REST nested router

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django and Django REST.

Trying to implement recommended routing scheme using nested router for each app.

Example:

**mysite.url.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^'+root_url+'/tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    url(r'^'+root_url+'/admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^'+root_url+'/swagger', swagger_schema_view),
    url(r'^'+root_url+'/', include('blog.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**blog.urls.py:**

```
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'^/blog', views.PostViewSet)
router.register(r'^/users', views.UserViewSet)
```

getting exception:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'blog.urls' from 'C:\\Users\\user11\\PycharmProjects\\api_v2\\blog\\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite you use `router` for url mapping, you still need an `urlpatterns` list.

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'^/blog', views.PostViewSet)
router.register(r'^/users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Also you could omit any regexp symbols in router urls:

```
router.register(r'blog', views.PostViewSet)
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
```